# How to put loader when the profile pic is changed using Angular2 or typescript

Tags: html, angular, css, typescript

I have a profile pic section, if i go to change pic, i need a loader until the profile pic is changed, and i also need the pic in background on which i had selected to change. I am trying to put loader but i am unable to do, i am not getting where i am going wrong, please help.

HTMl:

```
  <div id='loader' *ngIf="Loading" class="profilePicture">
    <div id="loaderDiv">
        <div></div>
    </div>
    <img class ="pre-bootstrap picture" src="{{user.imgpath}}">
</div>
```

Ts:

```
changeProfile(event) {
  this.Loading = true;
  var files = event.srcElement.files;
  var filename = files[0].name;
  var imgFile = new File([files[0]], filename, {type:files[0].type});
  var file_data = imgFile;
  this.ApiService
      .changeProfilePic(file_data,this.user_id)
      .subscribe(
        user => {
          this.Loading = false;
          this.user.imgpath = user.data;
          this.toasterService.pop('success', 'Profile Pic Changed!');
        },error => {
          this.Loading = false;
          this.toasterService.pop('error', 'Something went wrong!Please refresh and try');
        })
}
```

css:

```
#loaderDiv>div .profilePicture {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    width: 165px;
    height: 165px;
    margin: -95px 0 0 -75px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 3px solid transparent;
    border-top-color: #58B6A2;

}
img.pre-bootstrap.picture {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    z-index: 9999999;
    left: 33%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-left: 45px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 21%;
    border: solid 3px lightskyblue;
}
```

Comment: What error you get? i mean template error or syntax error? can you specify the detailed error statement?

Comment: thanks for response, i will update my code, now error is not coming, i want to put image which i have recently selected and i want a loader on the image untill the image gets uploaded to profile pic